# How do I remove a parent node in XML file based on text in a child element? Using Python 3.6

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Right now I'm attempting to use lxml in Python 3.6. I want to remove "Programs" if they contain hedge, and remove the "Request" altogether if none of the Programs contain 'keep'.
The xml is structured like this:

```
<Requests>
   <Request>
        <ProgramSelection>
            <Program> <![CDATA[hedge]]> </Program>
            <Program> <![CDATA[keep]] </Program>
        </ProgramSelection>
    </Request>
</Requests>
```

```
import lxml.etree


file_name = r'C:filename.xml'
parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
tree = lxml.etree.parse(file_name, parser)
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in tree.xpath("./Request[ProgramSelection/Program='hedge']"):
    root.remove(elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close. The following two xpaths select elements matching your remove criteria

```
import lxml.etree

file_name = r'test.xml'
parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
tree = lxml.etree.parse(file_name, parser)
root = tree.getroot()

# remove <Request> lacking a <Program>keep</Program>
for request in tree.xpath(
        "Request[not(ProgramSelection/Program[contains(text(),keep)])]"):
    request.getparent().remove(request)

# remove <Program>hedge</Program>
for program in tree.xpath(
        "Request/ProgramSelection/Program[contains(text(), hedge)]"):
    program.getparent().remove(program)

print(lxml.etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

And you can combine them into a bit less readable "or"

```
import lxml.etree

file_name = r'test.xml'
parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
tree = lxml.etree.parse(file_name, parser)
root = tree.getroot()

# remove <Request> lacking a <Program>keep</Program>
# remove <Program>hedge</Program>
for elem in tree.xpath("Request[
        not(ProgramSelection/Program[contains(text(),keep)])]"
        "|"        
        "Request/ProgramSelection/Program[contains(text(), hedge)]"):
    elem.getparent().remove(elem)

print(lxml.etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

Comment: Thanks! but this didn't seem to work. Does the keyword need to be in single quotes? like 'hedge' or ' hedge fund' if multiple words?

Comment: And the ProgramSelection has some peer elements, but the hierarchy is correct. Not sure if that matters, I’m not great with xml. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you use the `lxml` module, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. With this approach, no `for` loops or `if` logic is required. Plus, XSLT is portable and so can be run it well beyond Python.

Following script runs the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) to copy document as is and then runs two empty template on needed logic to remove their content.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space()'/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Program[contains(text(),'hedge')]"/>
  <xsl:template match="Request[not(contains(., 'keep'))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

doc = et.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('XSLT_Script.xsl')

transform = et.XSLT(xsl)    
result = transform(doc)

# OUTPUT TO SCREEN
print(result)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Requests>
  <Request>
    <ProgramSelection>
      <Program>keep</Program>
    </ProgramSelection>
  </Request>
</Requests>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/FZKT28403)</kbd>